# How to view regions of memory that are allocated by malloc in GDB core dump, is there any commands related to heap?

Tags: c, linux, gdb, heap-memory, coredump

I have potential memory corruption in of the code and I want to inspect heap memory.  I tried "info proc mappings" which doesn't have any heap memory allocation I guess.  so wanted to know if there is a way to check all the regions/chunks of memory that are being allocated by malloc.

Comment: Run your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Answer (score 0):

> I have potential memory corruption in of the code and I want to inspect heap memory.

This is highly non-trivial task. It requires understanding of `malloc` internals, and there are no tools that make this easy.

If your problem is reproducible, chances that running the program under Valgrind or building it with `-fsanitize=address` will point you right at the problem with minimal effort.